# Scala failing to resolve a type mismatch problem in a complicated code

Tags: scala, generics, types

I have the following setup and I am trying to pass the compile type checking of the code with preferably minimal modification as the code is being generated by a tool and not by hand.

I think the problem is I need to come up with a better definition for `T_MAX_LATTICE[T]` or `T_IntegerMaxLattice` in `M_TEST_COLL`.

The code is kind of large so I can't post the whole code here but I put the repo URL at the bottom. I am struggling to visualize the type hierarchy.

I know the question is too general but all I am looking for is being able to compile the code without using uncheck cast (or `asInstanceOf`)

```
type T_MAX_LATTICE[T] = T;

trait C_TEST_COLL[T_Result, T_T] extends C_TYPE[T_Result] with C_TINY[T_Result] {
  type T_IntegerMaxLattice;
  val t_IntegerMaxLattice : C_TYPE[T_IntegerMaxLattice] with C_MAX_LATTICE[T_IntegerMaxLattice,T_Integer];
  type T_Integers;
  val t_Integers : C_TYPE[T_Integers]with C_SET[T_Integers,T_Integer];


class M_TEST_COLL[T_T](name : String,val t_T : C_TYPE[T_T] with C_TINY[T_T])
  extends Module(name)
    with C_TEST_COLL[T_T,T_T]
{
  val t_Result : this.type = this;
  val t_IntegerMaxLattice = new M_MAX_LATTICE[T_Integer]("IntegerMaxLattice",t_Integer,0);
  type T_IntegerMaxLattice = T_MAX_LATTICE[T_Integer];
```

The error I am getting:

```
 Error:Error:line (42)type mismatch;
 found   : M_MAX_LATTICE[basic_implicit.T_Integer]
    (which expands to)  M_MAX_LATTICE[Int]
 required: C_TYPE[M_TEST_COLL.this.T_IntegerMaxLattice] with C_MAX_LATTICE[M_TEST_COLL.this.T_IntegerMaxLattice,basic_implicit.T_Integer]
    (which expands to)  C_TYPE[Int] with C_MAX_LATTICE[Int,Int]
  val t_IntegerMaxLattice = new M_MAX_LATTICE[T_Integer]("IntegerMaxLattice",t_Integer,0);
```

[Repo url](https://github.com/amir734jj/aps-type-problem/tree/e4af9e728791d68f9a423904e8f5bd42ebc56398)

Comment: I would recommend to read the documentation about Scala [code style](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/indentation.html) (e.g. avoid useless `;`) and [naming conventions](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html) (e.g. snake upper case type names ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess I created minimal example

```
  type T_MAX_LATTICE[T] = T;

  trait C_TEST_COLL[T_Result, T_T] extends C_TYPE[T_Result] with C_TINY[T_Result] {
    type T_IntegerMaxLattice;
    val t_IntegerMaxLattice: C_TYPE[T_IntegerMaxLattice] with C_MAX_LATTICE[T_IntegerMaxLattice, T_Integer];
    type T_Integers;
    val t_Integers: C_TYPE[T_Integers] with C_SET[T_Integers, T_Integer];
  }

  class M_TEST_COLL[T_T](name : String,val t_T : C_TYPE[T_T] with C_TINY[T_T])
    extends Module(name)
      with C_TEST_COLL[T_T,T_T] {
    val t_Result: this.type = this;
    val t_IntegerMaxLattice = new M_MAX_LATTICE[T_Integer]("IntegerMaxLattice", /*t_Integer,*/ 0);
    type T_IntegerMaxLattice = T_MAX_LATTICE[T_Integer];

    val t_Integers = ???/*new M_SET[T_Integer]("Integers",t_Integer);*/
    type T_Integers /*= /*TI*/T_SET[T_Integer];*/
  }

  trait C_TYPE[T_Result] /*extends C_BASIC[T_Result] with C_PRINTABLE[T_Result]*/
  trait C_TINY[T_Result] extends C_TYPE[T_Result]
  trait C_MAX_LATTICE[T_Result, T_TO] /*extends C_MAKE_LATTICE[T_Result,T_TO]*/
  type T_Integer = Int
//  val t_Integer = new M_INTEGER("Integer")
  trait C_SET[T_Result, T_ElemType] extends C_TYPE[T_Result] /*with C_COMPARABLE[T_Result] with C_COLLECTION[T_Result,T_ElemType] with C_ABSTRACT_SET[T_Result,T_ElemType] with C_COMBINABLE[T_Result]*/
  class Module(val mname : String)

  class M_MAX_LATTICE[T_TO]
  (name : String, /*t_TO:C_ORDERED[T_TO],*/v_min_element : T_TO) 
    /*extends M_MAKE_LATTICE[T_TO](name,t_TO,v_min_element,
      new M__basic_3[ T_TO](t_TO).v__op_z,
      new M__basic_3[ T_TO](t_TO).v__op_z0,
      new M__basic_13[ T_TO](t_TO).v_max,
      new M__basic_13[ T_TO](t_TO).v_min)
      with C_MAX_LATTICE[T_TO,T_TO] with C_ORDERED[T_TO]*/
```

I guess compile error is clear. You try to assign `new M_MAX_LATTICE[T_Integer]...` of type `M_MAX_LATTICE[Int]` to `t_IntegerMaxLattice` overriding a value of a different type.

If you make class `M_MAX_LATTICE` extend trait `C_TYPE` your code seems to compile

```
class M_MAX_LATTICE[T_TO]
(name : String, t_TO:C_ORDERED[T_TO],v_min_element : T_TO)
  extends M_MAKE_LATTICE[T_TO](name,t_TO,v_min_element,
    new M__basic_3[ T_TO](t_TO).v__op_z,
    new M__basic_3[ T_TO](t_TO).v__op_z0,
    new M__basic_13[ T_TO](t_TO).v_max,
    new M__basic_13[ T_TO](t_TO).v_min)
    with C_MAX_LATTICE[T_TO,T_TO] with C_ORDERED[T_TO]
    with C_TYPE[T_TO] //added
{
  val v_less = t_TO.v_less;
  val v_less_equal = t_TO.v_less_equal;
  val v_assert: T_TO => Unit = ??? //added
  val v_node_equivalent: (T_TO, T_TO) => T_OrLattice = ??? //added
  val v_string: T_TO => String = ??? //added
}
```