# Scala failing to resolve a type mismatch problem in a complicated generated code

Tags: scala, generics, types

I have the following setup and I am trying to pass the compile type checking of the code with preferably minimal modification as the code is being generated by a tool and not by hand.

I think the problem is I need to come up with a better definition for T_MAX_LATTICE[T] or T_IntegerMaxLattice in M_TEST_COLL.

The code is kind of large so I can't post the whole code here but I put the repo URL at the bottom. I am struggling to visualize the type hierarchy.

I know the question is too general but all I am looking for is being able to compile the code without using uncheck cast and minimal modification to runtime code (or basic.handcode.scala)

Errors (1 and 2):

```
Type mismatch. Required:
  C_NUMERIC [ T_IntegerMaxLattice ] 
  Found: M_MAX_LATTICE [ T_Integer ] 


Type mismatch. Required:
   C_NUMERIC [ T_IntegerMaxLattice ] 
   Found: M_MAX_LATTICE [ T_Integer ]
```

Generated code:

Problem #1:

```
class M_TEST_COLL[T_T](name : String,val t_T : C_TYPE[T_T] with C_TINY[T_T])
  extends Module(name)
    with C_TEST_COLL[T_T,T_T]
{
  type T_Result = T_T;
  val v_equal = t_T.v_equal;
  val v_string = t_T.v_string;
  val v_assert = t_T.v_assert;
  val v_node_equivalent = t_T.v_node_equivalent;
  type T_Root = t_T.T_Root;
  val t_Root = t_T.t_Root;
  type T_Wood = t_T.T_Wood;
  val t_Wood = t_T.t_Wood;
  val p_root = t_T.p_root;
  val v_root = t_T.v_root;
  val p_branch = t_T.p_branch;
  val v_branch = t_T.v_branch;
  val p_leaf = t_T.p_leaf;
  val v_leaf = t_T.v_leaf;

  val t_Result : this.type = this;
  val t_IntegerMaxLattice = new M_MAX_LATTICE[T_Integer]("IntegerMaxLattice",t_Integer,0);
  type T_IntegerMaxLattice = /*TI*/T_MAX_LATTICE[T_Integer];
  private class E_foo(anchor : Null) extends Evaluation[Null,T_IntegerMaxLattice](anchor,"foo") {
    override def getDefault = new M__basic_4[ T_IntegerMaxLattice](t_IntegerMaxLattice).v__op_s(1,2);
    override def compute : ValueType = c_foo();
  }
```

Problem #2:

```
  def c_foo() : T_IntegerMaxLattice = {
    Debug.begin("foo");
    try {
      return new M__basic_4[ T_IntegerMaxLattice](t_IntegerMaxLattice).v__op_s(1,2);
    } finally { Debug.end(); }
  }
```

[Repo url](https://github.com/amir734jj/aps-type-problem/tree/5cd432da0056b9af5c8754c7df17c340d7c5cb75)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to make `M_MAX_LATTICE` extend not only `C_TYPE` as in [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60134897/scala-failing-to-resolve-a-type-mismatch-problem-in-a-complicated-code) question but also `C_NUMERIC`

```
class M_MAX_LATTICE[T_TO]
(name : String, t_TO:C_ORDERED[T_TO],v_min_element : T_TO)
  extends M_MAKE_LATTICE[T_TO](name,t_TO,v_min_element,
    new M__basic_3[ T_TO](t_TO).v__op_z,
    new M__basic_3[ T_TO](t_TO).v__op_z0,
    new M__basic_13[ T_TO](t_TO).v_max,
    new M__basic_13[ T_TO](t_TO).v_min)
    with C_MAX_LATTICE[T_TO,T_TO] with C_ORDERED[T_TO]
    with C_TYPE[T_TO] with C_NUMERIC[T_TO]
{
  val v_less = t_TO.v_less;
  val v_less_equal = t_TO.v_less_equal;
  override val v_assert: T_TO => Unit = ???
  override val v_node_equivalent: (T_TO, T_TO) => T_OrLattice = ???
  override val v_string: T_TO => String = ???
  override def v_zero: T_TO = ???
  override def v_one: T_TO = ???
  override val v_plus: (T_TO, T_TO) => T_TO = ???
  override val v_minus: (T_TO, T_TO) => T_TO = ???
  override val v_times: (T_TO, T_TO) => T_TO = ???
  override val v_divide: (T_TO, T_TO) => T_TO = ???
  override val v_unary_plus: T_TO => T_TO = ???
  override val v_unary_minus: T_TO => T_TO = ???
  override val v_unary_times: T_TO => T_TO = ???
  override val v_unary_divide: T_TO => T_TO = ???
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I made more progress and now I am stuck with a null pointer exception. It would be great if you could checkout the question. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60368358/scala-getting-a-null-pointer-exception-how-to-fix-it-with-minimal-change